# Purchase of a license Laravel Backpack

Tags: laravel-backpack, license-key

Can I use license-key Backpack v3 on Backpack v4 version?

What to do if I use the temporary a.com domain later the project will be transferred to the b.com domain. When buying a license, which domain should I specify?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: That's something you should ask whoever sold you that license. We don't know the terms you agreed to

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems off-topic

Comment: The official page of [Laravel Backpack](https://backpackforlaravel.com/contact) for support use stackoverflow with tag "backpack-for-laravel" but tag doesn't work...

Comment: Well, as this is a community for programming-related questions, feel free to ask them here. Legal stuf (like your question) is off-topic here

Answer (score 0):

No, a v3 license will work inside Backpack v4. You have to purchase a separate license for v4. Unfortunately, you just missed huge Black Friday discounts.

No problem if you move from a.com to b.com, just email the Backpack team.

When upgrading from 3.x to 4.x make sure you follow each upgrade guide individually. For example:

- [upgrade Backpack 3.5 to 3.6](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/3.6)
- [upgrade Backpack 3.6 to 4.0](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.0)
- [upgrade Backpack 4.0 to 4.1](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.0)

They are all major versions. The first number signifies need for additional payment. The second number signifies breaking changes.